# Get number of columns and rows selected when a mouse hovers over a table with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

Based on an HTML table that creates the below image....

[image]

I need to allow a user to move there mouse over the table cells and as they go right and up/down have it add the CSS class to each cell that is in the covered space `SizeChooser-hover`.

When they select the desired columns and rows for there table and click it will then add the CSS class `SizeChooser-selected` to all cells in the square.

It will then also get me the number of columns and the number of rows into a variable in JavaScript.

Can anyone help me achieve this?  My JSFiddle here has the HTML for the table https://jsfiddle.net/qxavaja9/

add a CSS class `cell-selected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var columns;
var rows;
$(function() {
  $('td').hover(function() {
    var n = $(this).index();
    var m = $(this).parent('tr').index();
    $('td').removeClass('SizeChooser-hover');
    $('tr').each(function(y) {
      $(this).find('td').each(function(x) {
        if (x <= n && y <= m) {
          $(this).addClass('SizeChooser-hover');
        }
      })
    })
  }).click(function(){
    columns = $(this).index();
    rows = $(this).parent('tr').index();
    $('td').removeClass('SizeChooser-selected');
    $('td.SizeChooser-hover').addClass('SizeChooser-selected');
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qxavaja9/15/

`columns` and `rows` are what you want.

Comment: thanks this is awesome I couldn't find an example anywhere online!

Comment: Final product http://codepen.io/jasondavis/pen/eJBoeK uses your code to then generate the Markdown syntax for Markdown Tables.  Plenty of room for improvement but it works for now thanks again

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: This is just for the hover

```
$('table td').on('mouseover', function(){
    //remove the current selected
    $('table td').removeClass('SizeChooser-hover');
    //get the indices (position)
    var x = $(this).index();
    var y = $(this).parent().index();
    //iterate over each row
    $('table tr').each(function(){
        //if the row is less than or equal to the selected row
        if($(this).index() <= y){
            //iterate over each cell in the row
            $(this).children('td').each(function(){
                //if the cell is less than or equal; add the class
                $(this).toggleClass('SizeChooser-hover', $(this).index() <= x);
            });
        };
    });
});
```

On click, just toggle all SizeChooser-hover to Sizechooser-selected

```
$('table td.SizeChooser-hover').on('click', function(){
    $('.SizeChooser-hover').toggleClass('SizeChooser-hover Sizechooser-selected');
});
```

Comment: Thanks this is close https://jsfiddle.net/qxavaja9/14/ it has some strange behavior which you can see on the demo, any ideas for a fix?

Comment: I think it's because I forgot to update the `removeClass` method with the correct class.  I guess you can just use the other answer.